# Getting : Fatal error while I am trying to use the declare(strict_types=1) on my PHP file

Tags: php-7.2

I have created a php test script **test.php** with the following code :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

function sum(int $a, int $b) : int {
      return $a + $b ;
}

print(sum(2, 3));
```

Then when I try to run it, I am getting this fatal error:

```
Fatal error: strict_types declaration must be the very first statement in the script in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 2
```

I am using PHP 7.2.4 on Wampserver 3.1.3 and I am accessing the script through my browser.

Comment: is this script included into another one?

Comment: no, it is the only file I am using

Comment: This is weird, I'm using the same versions, php 7.2.4 on wamp 3.1.3 and I have no issue

Comment: The only way I could throw that exception using that code was using spaces before `<?php`, like tab, space or new line

Comment: The server Software is: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) PHP/7.2.4 - Port defined for Apache: 80

Comment: I am using exactly the same versions. Give a try to restart wamp

Comment: Thank you @cid, sadly the issue still exist after the restart. Also I made sure that there is no space before the php tag.

Comment: In php.ini, is `auto_prepend_file` set to something?

Comment: I checked auto_prepend_file, No value set for this, not even space there. Now I tried with 'none' then restarted apache. Still the same issue exist

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you save it in an editor that outputs a UTF-8 BOM? It's a few invisible bytes at the start of the file which mark it as Unicode, but PHP doesn't recognise it.

Try opening the file in Notepad, going to Save As and choosing the ANSI encoding.

Also make very sure there are no lines before the opening tag. It sounds like there is one.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem using php 7.1

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: for me it work with UTF-8 also.

Comment: Things might have changed since 2018.

Answer (score 1):

It also gives this error when extra spaces at the beginning. Should remove spaces specially before `<?php`

Comment: and also the first line of the php file `<?php declare(strict_types=1);` as line 1 starting on first char 1

Answer (score 1):

I used the script tag to solve that.
`<script>declare(strict_types=1);</script>`.
Remember this, put it in the first of body.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `<?php` is the first line of your script file. Even an empty new line will cause you this problem.

#### Wrong

[image]

#### Correct

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used utf-8 like that to solve:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
```